# Is there a Way to make OleDbConnection with ACE.OLEDB.12.0 work with as many excel formats as possible in .NET Framework C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-access, oledb

I have a problem that there is an app I have to fix
that works only under strict circumstances,
only with specific combinations of
MS Access and Excel, installed on my computer.

This is an x32 Windows Forms C# .Net Framework App.

Below, there is the code I got,
If the OLEDB isn't installed at all, it calls the "HelpUserInstallOLEDB" method,
But if there is a version of excel that can't work with my .xlsx file,
or the wrong version of the OLEDB is installed,
then the import just fails quietly.

I don't need to show the error to most users,
I want to make it work with as many excel apps installed as it's possible.

p.s. the code isn't mine,
I don't like it right the same as you don't like it.
I just need to add to it some stuff to make it work
with many versions of excel installed on Windows.

```
`public static void ImportFromExcel(string Lang, string Name, bool isNew, bool? exitOnCancel = false)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
            var globalization = new Globalization
            {
                CultureInfoName = Globalization.GetCulture(),
                UiFilePath = Path.GetUI_RELATIVE_PATH() + Name + ".uif"
            };
            var dlg = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                CheckPathExists = true,
                CheckFileExists = true,
                Multiselect = false,
                Filter = "Excel documents (.xlsx)|*.xlsx",
                FilterIndex = 0,
                RestoreDirectory = true,
                Title = "Import"
            };
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                String Filename = dlg.FileName;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                dt = new DataTable();
                if (Filename.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Data Source=" + Filename + @";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        HelpUserInstallOLEDB();
                        if (con != null)
                        {
                            con.Close();
                            con.Dispose();
                        }
                        if (dt != null)
                        {
                            dt.Dispose();
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                    try
                    {

                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [RAAD$]";

                        OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
                        myCommand.Fill(ds);
                        con.Close();
                        if (ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("ID")
                            && ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("CardNumber")
                            && ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("PoliceSector")
                            && ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("AccidentDistrict")
                            && ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("TypeDTP")
                            && ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("Fabula"))
                        {
                            dt = ds.Tables[0].Select().ToList().CopyToDataTable();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dt = null;
                            if (Lang == "En") MessageBox.Show("The excel file is different from the template");
                            if (Lang == "Ru") MessageBox.Show("Файл excel отличается от шаблона");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        if (Lang == "En") MessageBox.Show("File contents error ");
                        if (Lang == "Ru") MessageBox.Show("Проверяйте, в файле импорта есть ошибки");
                        return;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (con != null)
                        {
                            con.Close();
                            con.Dispose();
                        }
                        if (dt != null)
                        {
                            dt.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please, import a valid .xlsx file the next time");
                    return;
                }
                List<Accident> ListaFromXml = new List<Accident>();
                if (isNew)
                {
                    ListaFromXml = Database.ObjFromXml();
                    
                }
                List<Loguri> loguri = new List<Loguri>();
                Loguri loguno;
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    List<Accident> lstAccident = new List<Accident>();
                    Accident localAccident;
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        loguno = new Loguri();
                        loguno.ID = Database.ReadInt32(row["ID"]);
                        loguno.CardNumber = row["CardNumber"].ToString();
                        try
                        {
                            if (row["ID"] == DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                loguno.State = "ID is null";
                                loguri.Add(loguno);
                                continue;
                            }
                            string ores = "";
                            localAccident = null;
                            Database.LoadFromDataRow(row, out ores, out localAccident);
                            if (ores == "OK")
                            {
                                if (ListaFromXml != null && ListaFromXml.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    Accident elementul = ListaFromXml.Where(a => a.AccidentDateTime == localAccident.AccidentDateTime && a.Latitude == localAccident.Latitude && a.Longitude == localAccident.Longitude).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (elementul != null && elementul.ID > 0)
                                    {
                                        loguno.State = "Row already exist ...";
                                        loguri.Add(loguno);
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (localAccident != null) lstAccident.Add(localAccident);
                                if (lstAccident == null)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Empty object", String.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                    loguno.State = "Empty object";
                                    loguri.Add(loguno);
                                    continue;
                                }
                                loguno.State = "OK";
                                loguri.Add(loguno);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                loguno.State = ores;
                                loguri.Add(loguno);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            loguno.State = ex.Message;
                            loguri.Add(loguno);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    string LogName = "xls/SavedLog" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".txt";
                    string TextLog = " Import from excel " + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    TextLog = TextLog + " Log file - " + LogName + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    TextLog = TextLog + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    TextLog = TextLog + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(LogName);
                    foreach (Loguri s in loguri)
                    {
                        tw.WriteLine("ID - " + s.ID.ToString() + ";  CardNumber - " + s.CardNumber + "; STATE - " + s.State);
                        TextLog = TextLog + "ID - " + s.ID.ToString() + ";  CardNumber - " + s.CardNumber + "; STATE - " + s.State + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        tw.Close();
                        XmlDocument xmlFile = Database.ObjToXml(lstAccident);
                        string targetPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\xml\\xmlAccident.xml";
                        xmlFile.Save(targetPath);
                        if (Lang == "En") MessageBox.Show("File imported. ");
                        if (Lang == "Ru") MessageBox.Show("Файл импортирован");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error save file " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            } else if (exitOnCancel == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry you haven't Imported the file.\nIn order to avoid ugly, unwanted behavior\nRAAD will exit now", "See you soon!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                Application.Exit();
            }

        }`
```

Comment: Are you open to use something else? for example, there is https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus, or https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader.

Comment: The driver will read all excel files but you've got 2 Extended Properties in your connection string. Try taking out the second one. i.e. Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;